# Computing cohomology of hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, projective-geometry

I'm taking a course on differential geometry now, and we got the following exercise from the lecturer: *compute the (de Rham) cohomology groups $H_{dR}^i(M)$ of your favourite space*.

In all the examples I've seen, these groups are only calculated for easy spaces, like spheres, tori, or combinations of these, or spaces that can be built from these.

However, even for the basic example of a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$, the zero set of a polynomial in $n$ variables, I have no clue how to proceed.

So the question is this: let $M$ be the zero set in $\mathbb R^n$ of a smooth polynomial (i.e. such that the partial derivates and the polynomial share no zeros) in $n$ variables. *What is, and how can I compute the de Rham cohomology groups of $M$?*

If that makes it easier, assume the polynomial is homogeneous of degree $d$. Then how can one compute the de Rham cohomology groups of the corresponding projective hypersurface in $\mathbb {P}_{\mathbb R}^n$?

*Added:* For that matter, one could also ask the same question with $\mathbb R$ replaced by $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was Lefschetz hyperplane theorem but that is only for complex varieties.  I wonder if there is something analagous over the real numbers?  I'm thinking of this answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60324/lefschetz-hyperplane-section-theorem

Comment: The question with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by $\mathbb{C}$ is much easier thanks to the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, which computes all of the cohomology except the middle cohomology. Computing the middle cohomology is then equivalent to computing the Euler characteristic, which can be done in various ways, e.g. using a Riemann-Hurwitz style argument or using Chern classes.

Comment: @Seth: I do not believe there is anything like that in the real case: Every compact real orientable surface embeds in $R^3$ (as a real-algebraic surface).

Comment: If all you want is a more interesting example than spheres and tori, let $M$ be a smooth manifold acted on by a compact Lie group $G$. Then the de Rham cohomology of $M$ is canonically isomorphic to the de Rham cohomology of the $G$-invariant forms on $M$. In particular this leads to an algebraic recipe for computing the de Rham cohomology of homogeneous spaces $G/H$ in terms of Lie algebra cohomology.

Comment: (I also need to assume that $G$ is connected. The idea is that acting on forms by a one-parameter subgroup of $G$ is a homotopy.)

Comment: Anyway, I think the general question for real hypersurfaces is hard. Already it's not obvious how to compute $H^0$. Another thing that's true in the case of complex hypersurfaces that isn't true here is that the diffeomorphism type of such a hypersurface depends only on the dimension $n$ and the degree $d$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I will definetely look into the example with cohomology of homogeneous spaces.

Answer (score 6):

In [this post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/) I worked out, as an exercise, the answer for smooth projective complex hypersurfaces, not using de Rham cohomology. After applying the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, the basic tool is characteristic classes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general algorithm for computation of (co)homology groups of real-algebraic subsets in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Being a hypersurface does not particularly help in this computation. The algorithm goes back to Tarski's work (on elimination of quantifiers).

The entire book [Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540330984)  is pretty much all about such computations.

If you are dealing with complex projective varieties, then, in some range of dimensions, [Lefschetz hyperplane theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem) will allow you a dimension reduction. However, in the end of the day, you still have to do some dirty work (of algorithmic nature). See the book "[Stratified Morse Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642717160)", it is mostly about Lefschetz theorem in various forms. A good summary can be found [here](http://www.massey.math.neu.edu/Massey/Massey_preprints/SMT_survey.pdf).